# Definir diversas variáveis em apenas uma linha

Tags: linux, variáveis, refatoração, shell, bash

Gostaria de fazer um parser com apenas uma linha e quebrar uma string em diversas variáveis. Na *string* que vou fazer o parse, o padrão é que cada campo é separado por uma vírgula.

Em diversas linhas, o código para fazer o que eu quero seria assim:

```bash
hostname=`echo $tripa | cut -d, -f1`
ip=`echo $tripa | cut -d, -f2`
serial=`echo $tripa | cut -d, -f3`
```

Existe maneira de fazer isso em **apenas uma linha** (sem repetir o comando `cut` diversas vezes, uma para cada variável)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se vai funcionar para o seu caso.

```bash
tripa="meu host,127.0.0.1,abc"
IFS=',' read hostname ip serial <<<"$tripa"
echo -e "$hostname\n$ip\n$serial"
```

achei essa resposta [aqui](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-while-read-function-define-ifs-delimiter/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Ainda consegui colocar dentro dum script e ler a variável $tripa da entrada de um arquivo externo:

for tripa in $(cat $1 | cut -d, -f2,3,6); do
        IFS=',' read hostname ip serial <<<"$tripa"
        echo -e "$hostname\n$ip\n$serial"
done